# How to run Dash App in background/offline

Tags: python, flask, plotly, plotly-dash

I am new to dash app development and created a app which is running in the linux server. It is available to all users in our intranet only when I trigger and online. Once I logoff it is not accessible. How to schedule the app to run continuously even when I am offline. Any responses would be appreciated.

currently it is serving with below command

**python app.py**

I cant deploy in Heroku due to security restrictions. Docker also unavailable. Any other option would be appreciated.

Regards,
Sudheer

Comment: How did you launch the app on the server?  Do you SSH to the server and run it like `python app.py`?

Comment: Yes currently i am running as python app.py

Comment: Please add more details on how you are serving (running) the app and so one. Also try and search for tutorials on how to serve python applications, there are many out there.

Comment: I cant deploy in Heroku due to security restrictions. Docker also unavailable. Any other option would be appreciated.

Comment: servers which can run flask code should have special methods to start it. Some of them may use `Gunicorn` to run it. They can also use [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) to start application and control if it is still running and restart it if it is crush. Method `python app.py` is only to test code on local server.

Answer (score 1):

From this description, I guess that you

1. SSH into the server
2. Run `python app.py`
3. At this point, the app is available
4. Log off from the SSH connection (e.g. `exit` command)
5. At this point, the app is not available any more

If so, this is because the command you run during the SSH session will be terminated when you log off from the session.
There are several ways to keep your app running after you log off. For example,

- Run `nohup python app.py &`.
- Run `tmux` and run `python app.py` in the tmux window. Then `Ctrl+b+d` to close the tmux window.

In either way, the app will keep running after you log off from the SSH connection. If my guess about your situation is wrong, please elaborate on your situation more in detail. For example, tell us the series of command you run and what happens with them.

In particular, the term "offline" is not clear in this context. If you are completely offline and not connected even to the intranet, then there is no chance that you can use the app running on the server.

Comment: It's nohup instead of nohub.